# Why is my css not showing any changes

Tags: css, html

I am creating this simple html page... everything seems to work fine. But when I came to link my css to my html. Nothing happens and I made sure I save everything, nothing happens to my webpage. Can you check my code below and see if there is any problems thanks.

***HTML:***

```
<html>
    <head>
     <title>What if?</title>

        <meta http-equiv="What if" content="text/html; charset=uft-8"/>

    <img src="images/Logo.jpg" height="300" width="400"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
    </head>  

    <body>
    <header>
       <h1>What if</h1>
     </header>
    </body>   

</html>
```

***My CSS:***

```
    body {
    font-family : Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size : medium;
}
h1 {
    <center></center>
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Is your CSS file located in the same directory as your `index.html` ? And whats this `<center></center>` inside the stylings for `h1` ?

Comment: It worked WOOHOO! haha thanks man, the <center>, <center> is for me to center my header... Isn't that the way to do it? Sorry I am new to CSS

Comment: The fact that you have a HTML tag in your CSS rule is suspect. I'd remove that first.

Comment: @JamesKyorn `center` is a mostly deprecated HTML tag; it doesn't belong in CSS. There's an actual CSS rule used to center things.

Comment: If you want to center the text inside the header, I would advise to use `text-align: center`. I would suggest you to start from **[here (MDN CSS Getting started)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started)**.

Comment: Guys if you wanted to give the values of an image, say height and width how would you do it in CSS. Do you give your image an ID attribute, then you use that ID attribute to change the size and such.

Comment: Do not ask a new question in comments. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Also Don't use `<img>` tag into `<head>` section. `<img>` tag should be in `<body>` section.